# QuerySet of a ManyToManyField object is returning an empty list

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-models

I wanted to have a list of foreign keys for a field, so I had used Django's ManyToManyField.

I have the following models:

`models.py`

```py
class Community(models.Model):
    posts = models.ManyToManyField('Post', null=True, blank=True, symmetrical=False)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='+',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        symmetrical=False
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=50000, blank=True)
    comments = models.ManyToManyField('Comment', null=True, blank=True, symmetrical=False)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I'm able to view the list of foreign keys from the admin panel, but when I try to get the list of posts or members from the community object using `community_object.members.all()` and `community_object.posts.all()`, I get an empty list/queryset.

I'm new to Django and I don't think I understand ManyToManyFields very well.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Getting empty list or queryset not a problem it means you don't have any values inside your related tables or you've not added that values in *M2M* field.

Comment: You can learn more about many-to-many relationships in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).